# Python external evaluator missing first print

Tags: bugs, python, external-calls

Can you confirm this bug when evaluating Python code in Mathmatica?
Type `>` select Python by clicking on the icon on the left then paste the following code and execute:

```python
adj = ["red", "big", "tasty"]
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

for x in adj:
    for y in fruits:
        print(x, y)
```

I got output:

```
red banana
red cherry
big apple
big banana
big cherry
tasty apple
tasty banana
tasty cherry
```

I.e. `red apple` is missing for some reason.

I have 13.0.1 version of Mathematica and 3.9.0 Python.

Or even simpler example:

```python
for x in range(6):
    print(x)
```

---

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I.e. `0` is missing at the begining.

Comment: I can confirm [the same behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxtHy.png) in `13.0.0 Windows` (but not in `12.3.1 Windows`). Also, trying to see what is going on with `LinkSnooper` works fine in 12.3, but crashes the kernel in 13.0 ...

Comment: So it seems adding print() as the first line of code resolves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the first print is missing. I would guess it has been fixed by 13.3, but someone should confirm. But I would certainly call this a bug.

Comment: It seems to be [fixed in 13.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POyxn.png).